# Why I get "typings WARN deprecated <packagename> is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I get warning:

```
>typings ls
typings WARN deprecated 2016-08-05: "registry:dt/react#0.14.0+20160423065914" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
```

however, it seems that I have latest version:

```
>typings view dt~react --versions
TAG                   VERSION DESCRIPTION COMPILER LOCATION                                                                                                UPDATED
0.14.0+20160805125551 0.14.0                       github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/react/react.d.ts#edcbaabb56bb0866df95dbfdf279f4a680051217        2016-08-05T12:55:51.000Z
0.13.3+20160423065914 0.13.3                       github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/react/react-0.13.3.d.ts#3a44f976ba58e05adb666295d59168ef5e99ae17 2016-04-23T06:59:14.000Z
```

I see the tag is different, but when I try

```
typings i dt~react@0.14.0+20160805125551 -save -G
```

the version with latest tag is not installed.

Why I get the warning and how do I update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `--save` pay attention to `--`.
Or you can use `-S` instead.

See [documentation](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md) for more information.

Comment: oh, shit. That's why I don't like tools without GUI. Is there any way to update to latest version?

Comment: yes, just do not specify tag: `typings i dt~react -S -G`